# Javascript InfoVis Spacetree - Dynamically hide/show Tooltips

Tags: javascript, jquery, infovis, thejit, space-tree

I've been googling this and can't seem to find an answer. I will also ask this in the JavaScript InfoVis Toolkit Google Group.

I was wondering if it's possible to dynamically hide/show tooltips using InfoVis spacetree. Currently they are turned on and I have set up the tips like this:

```
Tips: {
        enable: true,
        type: 'HTML',
        offsetX: 10,
        offsetY: 10,
        onShow: function (tip, node)
        {
            tip.innerHTML = getToolTip(node);
        }
    },
```

but I can't seem to find any references for how I might turn them off later. For example, I want the user to be able to check a box to hide/show Tooltips and then display them accordingly. I tried *st.tips.hide()* (st is the name of my spacetree) but it doesn't do anything. If I do *alert(st.tips)* I get an object but I don't know what functions are available on the object.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I'm using ForceDirected and had a similar problem. I wanted to keep the tooltip displayed for a certain period of time after the user leaves the node with the cursor...

Calling

```
graph.tips.hide(false)
```

works for me (did you ever try passing an argument to hide?).
I can't tell you whether to pass true or false, they both work for me...

Overall you could try something like:

```
Tips: {  
      enable: true,
      type: 'HTMl',
      onShow: function(tip, node, isLeaf, domElement) {
          //Check if checkbox is checked
          var checked = $('input[type=checkbox]').is(':checked');

          if (checked == true){
            tip.innerHTML =  getToolTip(node);
          } else {
            graph.tips.hide(true);
          };
      }
```

In any case this is just an idea and I don't have the time to test it (pseudocode?..)

Hope this helped!

Cheers

Comment: Worked for me, thanks. The param determines whether the callback `this.config.onHide()` is triggered or not.